# NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - Mailchimp API

Tags: php, wordpress, mailchimp

I'm trying to add an email to a list using mailchimp API.
I'm using this code

```
// add user to mailchimp newsletter list
function addToMailChimp($email,$fname,$lname){
    require_once(get_stylesheet_directory().'/assets/Mailchimp.php');
    $apikey = '"xxxxxxxxxx-us7"';
    $list_id ="7xxxxxxxe";
    $MailChimp = new MailChimp($apikey);
    $result = $MailChimp->call('lists/subscribe', array(
        'id'                => $list_id,
        'email'             => array('email'=>$email),
        'merge_vars'        => array('FNAME'=>$fname, 'LNAME'=>$lname),
        'double_optin'      => false,
        'update_existing'   => true,
        'replace_interests' => false,
        'send_welcome'      => false,
    ));
    die(var_dump($result));
}
```

it does return an error:

> NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error -

I don't know how to tackle this issue

I'll appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: See comment,

```
$apikey = '"xxxxxxxxxx-us7"';
```

has single and double quotes around it leading to an incorrect API key causing your server to be unable to authenticate and returning a 500.

Comment: I fixed it, still the same problem

Comment: Hmm, why does `$apikey = '"xxxxxxxxxx-us7"';` have single and double quotes around it? That could lead to an incorrect API key causing your server to be unable to authenticate and returning a 500.

Comment: You're welcome! Edited my answer! Feel free to accept it :)